# jQuery left animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have this structure:

HTML:

```
<div id="side-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="img/once_sonra.png" alt="img1"></li>
    <li><img src="img/online_destek.png"alt="img2"></li>
    <li><img src="img/sizi_arayalim.png"alt="img3"></li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#side-menu {
    display:block;
    z-index:20;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    top:76px;
}​
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#side-menu").hide();
    //$(document).click(function() {
        $("#side-menu").slideDown().delay(500).slideUp();
    //});
});
```

​
Everything is working. But i don't want slide effect, want animate to left.

How can i do this?

Comment: ..have you tried using [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: try this page: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.animate`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dhVzq/2/)**

**[DEMO with Toggle left](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/dhVzq/4/)**

```
$("#side-menu").animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow")

or

var $lefty = $('#side-menu');
$lefty.animate({
  left: parseInt($lefty.css('left'),10) == 0 ?
    -$lefty.outerWidth() :
    0
});
```

Comment: Thank you but don't working. Please update jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/dhVzq/1/

Comment: Thank you! It's working on my site! Last question, how can i come back my div? So, first left 50px, after left -50px...

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.animate()**. For example:

```
$('#myElement').animate({left:'+=30px'});
```

for more info:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/